# AT command validation does not appear on the serial monitor

Tags: esp32, sim800

I can't validate an AT command. Would anyone have any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong? It should be printing **"Sending successful!** or **"Sending failed!"**, but it doesn't show any text.

```cpp
if (httpReadResponse.indexOf("OK") != -1) {
  Serial.println("Envio bem-sucedido!");
} else {
  Serial.println("Falha no envio!");
}
```

My serial monitor is printing this:

```
AT+HTTPDATA=192,5000\
DOWNLOAD\
OK\
AT+HTTPACTION=0\
OK\
AT+HTTPREAD
```

Full function:

```cpp
void sendHttpRequest(int distance_cm) {
  gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPINIT");
  gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPPARA=CID,1");
  gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPSSL=1");
  gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPPARA=URL," + url2 + "/" + distance_cm + "/" + id_cliente + "/" + id_caixa + "/" + ipadd1 + "/" + sinal + "/" + totalMilliLitres + "/" + vazao_atual + "/" + apikey);
  gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPPARA=CONTENT,application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPDATA=192,5000");
  gsm_send_serial("param=Aqualizar");
  gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPACTION=0");

  String httpReadResponse = gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPREAD");

  gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPTERM");

  if (httpReadResponse.indexOf("OK") != -1) {
    Serial.println("Sending successful!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Sending failed!");
  }
}
```

Comment: The declaration of `url2` may be important to interpreting `gsm_send_serial("AT+HTTPPARA=URL," + url2`... It would be better to provide all the variable declaration involved, if not compilable and testable code.

Comment: what is the value  of `httpReadResponse.indexOf("OK")`?

Comment: THE VALUE IS "OK" IN THE SERIAL

Comment: Print the value of the response,  ie. `Serial.println(httpReadResponse);`

Comment: `String httpReadResponse = gsm_send_serial ("AT+HTTPREAD");` How is function gsm_send_serial() defined ? You are clearly expecting it to return a String under the circumstances that you are using it. Also, which `Serial` instance is connected to the serial monitor? Does, for example, `Serial.println("Hello World")` work? Which serial instance is connected to the GSM device?

Comment: It would help, if you provide a minimal compilable example code, that demonstrates your problem. How is the SIM800 connected, that the Serial Monitor and the Arduino both see the modules AT answer?

Answer (score 0):

> AT+HTTPACTION=0

`AT+HTTPACTION=0` starts a GET session. Based on your code, you are supposed to create a POST session, which should be `AT+HTTPACTION=1`.

Read *SIM800 Series_IP_Application Note* which provides the examples for both GET and POST request based on the SIMCOM HTTP AT-command set. The application note can be found at SIMCOM's website (requires registration for free download) or simply google "SIM800 Series_IP_Application Note" as there are many sites that have the document available without the need for registration.